# reformulating the Conda powershell hook script as command line arguments for a VS Code profile

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

The command `conda init powershell` creates a default PowerShell profile that activates Conda when opening a PowerShell terminal via a script file containing this single line:

```
(& "path\to\conda\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
```

Rather than having Conda activate for every PowerShell terminal, I mimic this behavior in VS Code by placing that script in a different location and passing the arguments `["-noexit",  "& 'path\to\conda-init.ps1' "]` to a custom terminal profile.

This does not work on machines where the PowerShell `ExecutionPolicy` is set to `Restricted`. Is there a way to instead pass the script contents as arguments to PowerShell, rather than the script file itself?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need to be a powershell script at all.  You can use a batch script:

> `conda-init.bat`

```bash
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'path\to\conda\Scripts\conda.exe' shell.powershell hook"
```

Comment: This is a workaround and not actually an answer to my question. I am running a PowerShell terminal from an IDE (VSCode) and am trying to avoid passing a script to it. Also, your answer doesn't work for me since I do not have permissions to bypass the execution policy (otherwise I would just change my execution policy and run the script).

Comment: Have you looked at [-Encoded Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-encodedcommand-base64encodedcommand)?

Answer (score 0):

The Miniconda prompt created during Miniconda install runs using the command

```
%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'path\to\miniconda\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'path\to\miniconda' "
```

Which does use the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` command described by @maximilian-burszley. I can create an equivalent VS Code terminal profile in settings.json by adding the following entry to `terminal.integrated.profiles.windows`:

```json
"Conda": {
    "source": "PowerShell",
    "icon": "terminal-powershell",
    "overrideName": true,            
    "args": ["-ExecutionPolicy",  "ByPass", "-NoExit", "-Command",  "& 'path\\to\miniconda\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'path\\to\\miniconda' "]
}
```